# laravel relationship with more fields

Tags: php, laravel

I have this use case I have an attachments table containing id, id_target, target fields
I normally use it by joining both id_target and target, example

inner join attached to ON a.id_target = n and target = 'item'

is it possible to use the relationship in the model item with item::with(attachment)->get() ?

thank you very much

Comment: Please format the question properly and add the schema, model of the tables you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has some ambiguity, but if you want to represent a relationship and use Laravel's Eloquent `with()` conditional, you may be looking for something along these lines:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{ 

    ...

    public function attachment(){ 
    
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Attachment');

    }
}

?>
```

For which you could use as follows:

`Item::where(...)->with('attachment')->get();`

This does assume that your schema has the correct associations.

For more information on eager loading, read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Answer (score 0):

the solution for my question is realy basic.

I hadn't quite understood how he used relationships, then I saw with the query log, that relationships are managed with separate queries and not with joins.

so in my case it was enough to do this

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'items';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','name','price'
    ];

    public function attachs() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Attach','id_target', 'id')->where('target','=','item');
    }
}
```

i concat where method at relationship....

the for your times